# R transpose data set by group of variables

Tags: r, transpose

my data set look like this

```
name  attribute  value
Tom    age        20
Tom    height     80
Tom    weight     100
Jack   age        22
Jack   height     90
Jack   weight     110
```

and I want to get a data set like this

```
       Tom   Jack
age     20    22
height  80    90
weight  100   110
```

should be pretty stragiht forward in SAS by transpose of two variables
but it is not so in R , how can I do it ? I tried melt and transpose , but failed ....

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           text = "name  attribute  value
Tom    age        20
           Tom    height     80
           Tom    weight     100
           Jack   age        22
           Jack   height     90
           Jack   weight     110 ")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(value~attribute + name, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting R, I suggest you read Hadley Wickham and Garret Grolemund's new book [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/). In it, they introduce the `tidyverse` which may make certain operations easier. You can certainly use `xtabs` - and it's a fantastic tool, especially for constructing sparse matrices - but it can be a little esoteric if you're new.

For instance, with your dataset in a `data.frame`, you can use `tidyr` to reshape. Note that I also use `readr::read_table`, which avoids the `stringsToFactors` issue.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- read_table(
"name  attribute  value
Tom    age        20
Tom    height     80
Tom    weight     100
Jack   age        22
Jack   height     90
Jack   weight     110 ")

df1 %>%
    spread(name, value)

  attribute  Jack   Tom
*     <chr> <int> <int>
1       age    22    20
2    height    90    80
3    weight   110   100
```